# Output is 0 no matter what - how do I fix this?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program where one enters 2 pH values for the day for 3 days. I'm trying to show the average pH of the 3 days and the highest pH out of the 3 days. I'm not sure why the output for highest isn't being shown? It should show 4 if my highest pH out of the 3 days is 4, but after running my module, my answer comes out as 0? I'm clueless on how else I should do this.

```
highest=0.0
fhighest=0.0
count=1
while count <=3:
    ph1=float(input("Enter morning pH value: "))
    ph2=float(input("Enter night pH value: "))
    totalph= ph1+ph2
      
    if ph1>ph2:
              ph1=highest
    else:
        ph2=highest

        if highest>fhighest:
            highest=fhighest
        else:
            fhighest=highest

    count=count+1

average=totalph/3
print("Average: ", average)
print("Highest: ", highest)
```

Comment: `if highest>fhighest: highest=fhighest` I guess that should be `fhighest=highest` (and the `else` does not make sense at all either way). Also, the average should be `/ 6` I think. And `totalph` is only the sum of the last two values, not of all of them.

Comment: Syntax `<variable I'm setting the value of> = <variable that has the value or the value itself>` I believe you have all of your variable assignments inside your `if/else` block backwards. Switch all of them. Like: instead of `ph1=highest` it should be `highest=p1`.

Comment: Why use a `while` loop at all? `for _ in range(3): ...`. You never actually *use* the value of `count` except to control the loop.

Comment: `ph1=highest` and `ph2=highest` sets ph1 or ph2 to the value of `highest` (0), rather than setting `highest` to the value of ph1 or ph2

Comment: `highest = max(ph1, ph2)` and `fhighest = max(fhighest, highest)`. No need to use `if` statements just to increase the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that you don't add to `totalph`, you reassign it, thus `average` will not be correct. Instead you should `totalph += ph1+ph2`. Moreover, to find the average you should divide by 6, not 3 (because you have 6 measurements total). Secondly, the way you find the highest is overcomplicated. It can be done easier:

```
highest=0.0
count=1
totalph = 0
while count <=3:
    ph1=float(input("Enter morning pH value: "))
    ph2=float(input("Enter night pH value: "))
    totalph += ph1+ph2
    highest = max(highest, max(ph1, ph2))  
    count=count+1

average=totalph/6
print("Average: ", average)
print("Highest: ", highest)
```

It can be simplified even further with using lists:

```
ph_measurements=[]
n_days = 3
for count in range(n_days):
    ph_measurements.append(float(input("Enter morning pH value: ")))
    ph_measurements.append(float(input("Enter night pH value: ")))

print("Average: ", sum(ph_measurements)/(n_days*2))
print("Highest: ", max(ph_measurements))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have problem in your assignments, if you want to assign a value to highest ph, you should use highest=ph1, not ph1=highest.
And in your average calculation, you are just dividing your last day phs to 3, not your 3 day ph summation. Use += to add new day ph to total ph. (you need to declare your totalph variable before your loop, like highest and other vars)

Answer (score 0):

just edit this part. You are doing assignments in the wrong way. The value of ph* is supposed to be assigned in the highest variable, not the other way around.

```
  if ph1>=ph2:
    highest = ph1
  else:
    highest = ph2
```

and this should work for correctly getting the answer of avg ph .

```
highest=0.0
fhighest=0.0
count=1
while count <=3:
  ph1=float(input("Enter morning pH value: "))
  ph2=float(input("Enter night pH value: "))
  totalph += ph1+ph2
    
  if ph1>=ph2:
    highest = ph1
  else:
    highest = ph2

    if highest>fhighest:
        highest=fhighest
    else:
        fhighest=highest

  count=count+1

average=totalph/6
print("Average: ", average)
print("Highest: ", highest)
```